# Changing Userid in powerbi embed link

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

So I have a powerbi url shared by powerbi team in my company. But the thing is when I open that in my angular project in a iframe it opens and logged in to the system userid. What I want to do is login using a different userid which is not my username.
But powerbi url always takes logged in person userid.

Can anyone please suggest anything.

I tried adding ?&username=different&password=password

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use another identity for the embedding you must use "[Embed for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/powerbi-implementation-planning-usage-scenario-embed-for-your-customers)".  You can use a different "Master User" to generate the embedding token, or provide an "effective identity" in the embedding token.